# Export command history in Rstudio

Tags: export, rstudio, history

I am trying to export all the command history from Rstudio in Mac. But in the "History" tab or using  `savehistory(file = ".Rhistory")`, only about 500 hundred latest commands are exported. However, when I directly search commands, I can see the commands way earlier than these 500 commands, for example half of a year ago. So where does Rstudio store all these histories? How can I export them? If the final history contains the date of the commands that I input, it would be even better. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 4):

After searching with the same question, here's an answer in case anyone else comes across the same issue:

`savehistory` is a base R function that will save everything from the current session, whereas RStudio has a seperate database that the history window uses. The location of this depends on your operating system (more info [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State)).

Windows:
`%localappdata%\RStudio`

macOS:
`open ~/.local/share/rstudio`

Once you've located the `history_database`, [this](https://gist.github.com/vzemlys/751887b31657649a6a5c) helpful code by @[vzemlys](https://gist.github.com/vzemlys) allows you to export the contents to a text file with "nicer formatting" (i.e. data and time stamps for each line of code history):

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
library(bit64)
library(stringr)

lns <- readLines("yourfilelocation/history_database") %>% str_split(pattern=":",n=2)
hist_db <- data_frame(epoch=as.integer64(sapply(lns,"[[",1)),history=sapply(lns,"[[",2))

hist_db %<>% mutate(nice_date = as.POSIXct(epoch/1000,origin = "1970-01-01",tz = "EET"))
hist_db %<>% mutate(day = ceiling_date(nice_date,unit = "day")-days(1))

hist_db %<>% dplyr::select(-epoch)

dd <- hist_db$day %>% unique %>% sort

ff <- "hist_nice.txt"
cat("R history","\n",rep("-",80),"\n",file=ff,sep="")

for(i in 1:length(dd)) {
    cat("\n\n",format(dd[i]),"\n",rep("-",80),"\n",file=ff,sep="",append=TRUE)        
    hist_db %>% filter(day==dd[i]) %>% dplyr::select(nice_date,history) %>% arrange(nice_date) %>% 
        write.table(ff,sep="\t", quote=F, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
}
```

Example output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
R history
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2022-06-08
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-06-08 13:32:57 test <- testfile %>% pivot_wider(names_from=scenario, values_from=sst) %>% na.omit()
2022-06-08 13:32:57 ggplot() + theme_bw() +
2022-06-08 13:32:57 geom_tile(data = test, aes(x,y,colour=layer), alpha=0.8) +
2022-06-08 13:32:57 scale_color_viridis() +
2022-06-08 13:32:57 coord_equal() +
2022-06-08 13:32:57 theme(legend.position="bottom") 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just a quick note: make sure you have a folder named Database in your working directory. Otherwise you might get an error message

Comment: Good catch! I edited the code to remove this, it should run smoothly without error messages